# GWT: How to use private tag for locale

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization, locale

I'm making an web app using GWT i18n. In this app, I would like to set up a custom property files to support differences from main language. For example I have an `en_US` locale, but also I would like to have `en_US_x_custom` support with some redefined property fields (specifications of BCP 47 says that I can use `-x` tag for private tag support).

Let me show what I have for now:

I have an interface

```
public interface TestMsg extends Messages {
    String value();
}
```

and few property files:

- `TestMsg_en_US.properties`
- `TestMsg_en_US_x_custom.properties`

In `app.gwt.xml`, I have this lines

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.CldrLocales"/>
<extend-property name="locale" values="en_US"/>
<extend-property name="locale" values="en_US_x_custom"/>
```

However, the problem is that compilations fails with following messages:

```
[ERROR] Type com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.LocaleInfoImpl_en_US_X-custom could not be referenced because it previously failed to compile with errors:
      Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.LocaleInfoImpl_en_US_X-custom'
         [ERROR] Errors in 'generated://74EF808C0035420F02374EADB97661B8/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/impl/LocaleInfoImpl_en_US_X-custom.java'
            [ERROR] Line 10: Syntax error on token "-", < expected
            [ERROR] Line 17: The method getLocaleQueryParam() of type LocaleInfoImpl_en_US_X must override or implement a supertype method
            [ERROR] Line 10: The public type LocaleInfoImpl_en_US_X must be defined in its own file
            [ERROR] Line 22: The method getDateTimeFormatInfo() of type LocaleInfoImpl_en_US_X must override or implement a supertype method
            [ERROR] Line 10: Syntax error, insert "AdditionalBoundList1" to complete TypeParameter1
            [ERROR] Line 27: The method getNumberConstants() of type LocaleInfoImpl_en_US_X must override or implement a supertype method
            [ERROR] Line 12: The method getLocaleName() of type LocaleInfoImpl_en_US_X must override or implement a supertype method
   [ERROR] Errors in 'com/google/gwt/i18n/client/LocaleInfo.java'
      [ERROR] Line 37: Rebind result 'com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.LocaleInfoImpl_en_US_X-custom' could not be found
```

How do I get rid of this compilation error? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<extend-property name="locale" values="en_US-x_custom"/>` (notice the dash after `en_US`) to match the properties file? Or the other way around. Either way, triple check the filename matches the locale you define in your module file.

Comment: I tried both ways of defining. With the way that you adviced I got following error: [ERROR] Line 13: Invalid property value 'en_US-x_custom'

Comment: I see - I just wanted to make sure. Well, in that case I'd wager this is either a bug or something not supported by GWT. You can report it on the GWT bugtracker unless someone else finds a solution here. Or dig yourself deeper: look at the generated class to see why it's not compiling (there's a switch that forces the GWT compiler to leave the temporary generated classes), see the `LocaleInfoGenerator` class to see how the `LocaleInfoImpl*` classes are generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ommit `-x` part of the locale. Then you can specify the locale as `en_US_custom` and have property file named `TestMsg_en_US_CUSTOM.properties` (notice capital letters).

Comment: It worked without -x part in previous version of GWT (2.3). Now I'm switched to GWT 2.7 and after compiling I got following error:  [ERROR] Generator 'com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.LocalizableGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding 'com.package.TestMsg'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized locale format: en_US_CUSTOM  at com.google.gwt.i18n.server.GwtLocaleFactoryImpl.fromString(GwtLocaleFactoryImpl.java:198)

Comment: Strange, I was testing it with GWT 2.7. Try setting a breakpoint in `GwtLocaleFactoryImpl.fromString()` and see why this locale throws an error. It should be parsed as: `language: en`, `script: null`, `region: US`, `variant: custom`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used more short name, than "custom". In GwtLocaleFactoryImpl "variant" is defined if ((len >= 5 && len <= 8) || (len == 4 && Character.isDigit(part.charAt(0)))), so in my case I was getting "Unrecognized locale format" exception. Now it works.